# TypeScript Definition for Onsen UI

Tags: typescript, onsen-ui

From here https://www.nuget.org/packages/onsenui.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped/

I notice that there is only one version 0.0.1 TypeScript Definition for Onsen UI and stay there for a while (April 07 2015).

Is this 0.0.1 still corresponding to the latest Onsen UI v1.3.11?

If not, will there possibility be an update for it?

Much appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't correspond to Onsen UI 1.3.11 but it's almost 100% compatible because the Onsen elements structure has not changed that much.

Answer (score 4):

These days type definition files are installed using `tsd` not nuget. You can install `tsd` via `npm`.

```
npm install tsd
```

Then install Onsen UI:

```
tsd install onsenui
```

The Onsen UI team has [recently published](http://onsen.io/blog/type-definitions-onsenui-typescript/) a blog post about the TypeScript support, you can take a look to learn more about it.

Comment: Good answer. Recommend `npm install tsd -g` 